# PostGIS: Syntax for ST_Collect into a multipolygon keeping internal boundries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, multi-polygon

I have a PostGIS table with many polygons representing islands these all form a common group

How do I create a new MultiPolygon  (keeping internal boundaries) and give it a new name?

```
CREATE TABLE multypoly_test
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,                
    name character varying(30),
    geom geometry(geometry,4326)
);

INSERT INTO multypoly_test (name,geom) 

SELECT 'MyName', ST_Collect( SELECT * FROM geo_table_wgs84 WHERE file_name = 'MyFileName' ) );
```

From the [Examples - Array variant](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) in the manual

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 3: SELECT 'MyName', ST_Collect( SELECT * FROM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a query within a function call, it must be enclosed in another set of parentheses `select myfunction((select .. from ..))`

But this won't be necessary for this query. `ST_Collect` expects a geometry field, not a table and even less record(s) with something else but geometries.

```sql
INSERT INTO multypoly_test (name,geom) 
SELECT 'MyName', ST_Collect(geom)
FROM geo_table_wgs84 
WHERE file_name = 'MyFileName';
```

**edit** since it seems you have a mix of polygons and multipolygons in the input, you can use `st_dump` to get only simple polygons before doing the aggregation

```sql
INSERT INTO multypoly_test (name,geom) 
SELECT 'MyName', ST_Collect(geom)
FROM 
  (SELECT (st_dump(geom)).geom --add other fields as needed
   FROM geo_table_wgs84 
   WHERE file_name = 'MyFileName') sub;
```

Comment: Hi both answers produced a row in the test table viewing it in qgis produces a non geo feature and doesn't show anything `SELECT name,ST_AsText(geom) ` gives `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON..`  am I missing something?

Comment: @TonySansom your input is likely a mix of polygons/multipolygons, so the output of st_collect is a collection. See edit to see how to overcome this

Comment: That gives MULTIPOLYGON but still nothing in qgis

Comment: The geometry should be fine. It might be faster if the column was `geometry(multipolygon,4326)`. Let's note that there is no PK in your query, you may want to add one.

Comment: Pretty sure `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` produces PK? 
In pgAdmin4 => Geometry Viewer The geometry looks fine but not in qgis

Comment: ah yes, sorry for the PK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the **ST_Collect** function expects a geometry column.
To do this, you must use a **subquery**.

Here is an example:

```sql
SELECT ST_Collect(tmp.geometry)
FROM (SELECT geometry FROM geo_table_wgs84 WHERE file_name = 'MyFileName') as tmp
```